# What is the proper etiquette for answering old questions?

Tags: discussion, etiquette

While searching for questions/answers regarding a particular character, I came across a question that I considered answering. The question is still open, relevant, and doesn't have an accepted answer, but it was first asked over 4 years ago. Since I'm not familiar with the etiquette here on StackExchange, I'm not sure if it'd be appropriate to respond or not.

To be more specific, this is the question I'm referring to: [Is Boba Fett alive in the new canon?](https://scifi.stackexchange.com/questions/114977/is-boba-fett-alive-in-the-new-canon)

At the time, no definitive answer could be provided about the character's status within the current Star Wars canon. However, with the release of the latest episode of Disney's "The Mandalorian," a definitive answer can be provided. To that end, I would like to respond. However, I don't know if doing so would be frowned upon given the question's age.

Comment: Hi and welcome to SciFi stackexchange, I don't know if you need to see the [tour] as you've already found meta! But it's there all the same just in case. This is a great meta question to ask, so thank you very much.

Comment: Thanks for asking this question; I'd wondered about this myself.

Answer (score 35, accepted):

By all means, answer it!  Unanswered questions are a blight that needs to be fixed!

(To more be more specific:  if a question hasn't been closed, then old questions definitely need love.  There are even badges specifically for providing good answers to old questions.)

Comment: It may be worth mentioning that [the single highest voted answer on SciFi SE](//scifi.stackexchange.com/a/105743) was to a question that had been unanswered for 4½ years.

Comment: @benrg Not only that, it's also [the most bountied answer on the entire SE network](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/269080/278659).